# Vaadin: make CDI and ThreadLocal be friends

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin, cdi

Is it possible to use the CDI's `@Inject` annotation when working with a ThreadLocal variables?
There is a snippet:

```
@VaadinScoped(VaadinScope.APPLICATION)
 public class AdminApplication extends AbstractCdiApplication implements HttpServletRequestListener {

 private static ThreadLocal<AdminApplication> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<AdminApplication>();

 @Inject
 private Instance<Lang> lang;

 @Override
 public void init() {
    setInstance(this);
    setLocale(Lang.RU_RU);
    setMainWindow(new LoginWindow());
 }

 @Override
 public final void setLocale(Locale locale) {
    getInstance().lang.get().setLocale(locale);
    super.setLocale(locale);
 }

    public static AdminApplication getInstance() {
    return threadLocal.get();
 }

 public static void setInstance(AdminApplication application) {
       threadLocal.set(application);
 }

 @Override
 public void onRequestStart(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  {
    AdminApplication.setInstance(this);
 }
```

when I try to call these methods:

```
public void authenticate(String login, String password) throws Exception {
    if ("user".equals(login) && "querty".equals(password)) {
        loadProtectedResources();
        return;
    }

    throw new Exception("Login failed!");
}

private void loadProtectedResources() {
    String mainWindowCaption = getInstance().lang.get().getText("mainwindow-name");
    setMainWindow(new Window(mainWindowCaption));
}
```

I usually get a NullPointerException cause the `getInstance().lang.get()` is null.

The Lang is:

```
@VaadinScoped(VaadinScope.APPLICATION)
public class Lang implements Serializable, TextBundle {...}
```

It is interesting that if I use the `@EJB` annotation, the injected ejb is there (not null). The other thing is the `getInstance().lang` is the Default Instance (see this in the debug), but when I call `getInstance().lang.get()` it is null.

I've tried to use the straight reference `@Inject private Lang lang;`, but it seem that CDI add on with the HttpServletRequestListener doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 0):

The 'ThreadLocal pattern' was originally used to make HTTP request data and Vaadin application instance easily available to the rest of the Vaadin application - without passing variable references around.

That said, I think you should be fine without any ThreadLocal variables if using CDI. Just use RequestScoped and VaadinScoped variables wherever you need them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried this, but it seems that the problem with initialization/inject chain...